# Telegram bot not responding when mentionned

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a little bot in python with the library `python-telegram-bot`, and I am stucked with a little problem :

I have an `InlineKeyboardButton` with the parameter `switch_inline_query_current_chat`, so when the user click on it, a command is automatically written in its chat.

But, that command is preceded with the mention of the bot (with an @).

The problem is my bot isn't answering in that case, and I have no idea why..

Is there a solution to make the button do not preced the command with the mention of the bot ?

From `@BotFather` the groups are allowed and the privacy group is turned off.

Thank you a lot

Edit : This is the code for the CommandHandler :

```
def getEntry(update, context):
if not (is_allowed_user(update.message.from_user.username, 'getEntry')):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text='Who the hell are you @' + update.message.from_user.username + ' ?')
    return
search = ' '.join(context.args)

infos, err = get_infos_people(search)

if err is not None:
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=err)
    return

context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=beautify_infos(infos),
                         parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN, reply_markup=getMainKeyboard(infos))
get_handler = CommandHandler('get', getEntry, filters=~Filters.update.edited_message)
```

And this is the code for the buttons :

```
def getMainKeyboard(infos):
keyboard = [InlineKeyboardButton("modify",
                                  switch_inline_query_current_chat="/get " + infos[0] + "<write here>")]]
return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

Comment: Please share your code, especially the commandhandler!

Comment: Sure ! I just edited my post to add some code !

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**Note:** I'm no python-telegram-bot expert, but the issue/fix should be non-lib related</sup>

---

Your [`commandHandler()`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html) is defined as so:

```
get_handler = CommandHandler('get', getEntry, filters=~Filters.update.edited_message)
```

This links the `/get` command to the `getEntry` handler.

---

**Issue**

Since the command is *only* fired at `/get`, you'll need to add a second command with the name of the bot so it will register that command as-well;

```
get_handler = CommandHandler([ 'get', 'get@myBot' ], getEntry, filters=~Filters.update.edited_message)
```

<sub>The first argument (`command`) accepts both a `str` or a `list` as the [docs shows](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html#telegram.ext.CommandHandler.command)</sub>

---

Had the same issue in some other library, don't think there is a 'cleaner' way of handeling this.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for the answer, mine is late cause a lot of work. Anyway, unfortunately this is not working. `Command is not a valid bot command` because of the @ I presume. I will try by catching every message, and filter by myself, without help of the library.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I;ll guess you have to file a bug report to the library since this should work